# Python questions(Convolution)

Tags: python, numpy

```
h = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
x = np.array([0.5, 2, 0, 0, 0])

length = len(h)+len(x)-1

h_conv, h_rev, x_conv, y_conv = np.zeros(length), np.zeros(length), np.zeros(length), np.zeros(length)
x_conv[:len(x)] = x
h_rev[length-len(h):] = h[::-1].copy()

for t in range(length):
    h_conv[:t+1] = h_rev[length-t-1:]
    y_conv[t] = np.sum(x_conv * h_conv)

>>> y
[0.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

How do I write the three lines for the for-loop without using pre-defined methods?

I tried:

```
for i in range(length):
    y[i]=0;
    for j in range(length):
        y[i] += x[i-j]*h[j];


Error index 0 is out of bounds for axis with size 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `j` can be greater than `i`. did you mean:

```
for i in range(length):
    y[i]=0;
        for j in range(i):
        y[i] += x[i-j]*h[j];
```

or possibly `i+1`...